# using filename as column headers in data frame

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I had multiple excel files and i needed to collate one column from all of them into a dataframe. I used the below code:

```
my_excel_files = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\......\Documents\*.xlsx")

total_dataframe = pd.DataFrame() 

for file in my_excel_files:
    df = pd.read_excel(file, header = 1) 
    new_df = df['Comments']
    total_dataframe = pd.concat([total_dataframe, new_df], axis=1)
```

this code gets all the 'Comments' columns from all my excel files and appends them together in total_dataframe. the issue is the columns in that data frame are all 'Comments' so i can't distinguish where each column came from.

Is there a way to use the full file names of each excel as the column header instead so that I'd know which excel each column came from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create list of Series with `append` or list comprehension and then use `keys` parameter in [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
import glob, os

my_excel_files = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\......\Documents\*.xlsx")
names = [os.path.basename(f).split('.')[0] for f in my_excel_files]

output = []
for file in my_excel_files:
    df = pd.read_excel(file, header = 1) 
    new_df = df['Comments']
    output.append(new_df)

final = pd.concat(output, axis=1, keys=names)
```

Or:

```
import glob, os

my_excel_files = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\......\Documents\*.xlsx")
names = [os.path.basename(f).split('.')[0] for f in my_excel_files]

output = [pd.read_excel(file, header = 1)['Comments']  for file in my_excel_files]
final = pd.concat(output, axis=1, keys=names)
```